# how to mask embed scrollview scroll seamless

Tags: ios, scroll, uiscrollview

I have two scrollview, s1, s2
s2 was embed in s1

[image]

I hope they can scroll seamless, but not sure how to?
[code example](https://github.com/ruandao/NestedScroll)

tks.

on apple's docs, it say [scrollview support same-direction scrolling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html)

but, it was not scroll seamless, parent scrollview never transfer velocity to embed scrollview, you have to drag again, after parent scroll view scroll to bottom, to make the inner scrollView scroll

and I had been search many similar question, but not get any useful suggest:

[iOS nested scrollview — keep scrolling past top into superview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265257/ios-nested-scrollview-keep-scrolling-past-top-into-superview)

Answer (score 0):

I got the method

1. First, set `parent scrollview's contentsize` to  `inner scrollView's contentSize` + `other view's height`
2. use scrollview's delegate method `func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)` to observer `contentOffset` and change inner scrollView's contentOffset manually

however, this will make scrolling very slow...